# how to get an if statement to restart from a certain line of code in java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

I am a student who is relearning java and I am looking for a way to have player 2 rolls again (since if a player rolls a double they get to roll again), however, if I use `continue` then it will jump back to the top of the do while statement. Any ideas would be appreciated! 
here is the code:

```
/A2.java
/to simulate a double dice game between 2 players; the first one to reach a  
score of 75 wins

public class A2
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
{
  //intitialize variables
  int playerOneScore = 0;
  int playerTwoScore = 0;
  int win = 75;
  do {
    //PLAYER 1
    int diceOne = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    int diceTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    int sum = diceOne+diceTwo;
    playerOneScore=playerOneScore+sum;
    if (diceOne==diceTwo)
    {
      System.out.println ("player 1 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
      System.out.println ("player 1 now has a score of : "+playerOneScore);
      //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
      if (playerOneScore>win)
      {
        break;
      }
      System.out.println ("player 1 now gets to roll again");
      sum=0;
      continue;
    }
    else if (diceOne!=diceTwo)
    {
      System.out.println ("player 1 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
      System.out.println ("player 1 now has a score of : "+playerOneScore);
      sum=0;
    }
    //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
    if (playerOneScore>win)
    {
      break;
    }
    //PLAYER 2
    diceOne = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    diceTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    sum = diceOne+diceTwo;
    playerTwoScore=playerTwoScore+sum;
    if (diceOne==diceTwo)
    {
      System.out.println ("player 2 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
      System.out.println ("player 2 now has a score of : "+playerTwoScore);
      //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
      if (playerOneScore>win)
      {
        break;
      }
      System.out.println ("player 2 now gets to roll again");
      sum=0;
 //**********************THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS***********************
      continue;
    }
    else if (diceOne!=diceTwo)
    {
      System.out.println ("player 2 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
      System.out.println ("player 2 now has a score of : "+playerTwoScore);
      sum=0;
    }
    //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
    if (playerOneScore>win)
    {
      break;
    }
  }while (playerOneScore<=win && playerTwoScore<=win );
  if (playerOneScore>win)
  {
    System.out.println ("player 1 wins with a score of : "+playerOneScore);
  }
  else if (playerTwoScore>win)
  {
    System.out.println ("player 2 wins with a score of : "+playerTwoScore);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

sorry for the terrible formatting

EDIT: It works now, thank you Scary Wombat for helping me!
below is the working code in case someone else also has a similar question:

```
//A2.java
//to simulate a double dice game between 2 players; the first one to reach a 
score of 75 wins

public class A2
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
{
 {
  //intitialize variables
  int playerOneScore = 0;
  int playerTwoScore = 0;
  int win = 75;
  do {
    //PLAYER 1
    int diceOne = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    int diceTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    int sum = diceOne+diceTwo;
    playerOneScore=playerOneScore+sum;
    if (diceOne==diceTwo)
    {
      System.out.println ("player 1 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
      System.out.println ("player 1 now has a score of : "+playerOneScore);
      //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
      if (playerOneScore>win)
      {
        break;
      }
      System.out.println ("player 1 now gets to roll again");
      sum=0;
      continue;
    }
    else if (diceOne!=diceTwo)
    {
      System.out.println ("player 1 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
      System.out.println ("player 1 now has a score of : "+playerOneScore);
      sum=0;
    }
    //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
    if (playerOneScore>win)
    {
      break;
    }
    //PLAYER 2
    boolean t=true;
    while (t){
      diceOne = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
      diceTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
      sum = diceOne+diceTwo;
      playerTwoScore=playerTwoScore+sum;
      if (diceOne==diceTwo)
      {
        System.out.println ("player 2 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
        System.out.println ("player 2 now has a score of : 
"+playerTwoScore);
        //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
        if (playerOneScore>win)
        {
          break;
        }
        System.out.println ("player 2 now gets to roll again");
        sum=0;
        //NEED TO FIX, KEEPS JUMPING TO BEGINING AGAIN
        continue;
      }
      else if (diceOne!=diceTwo)
      {
        System.out.println ("player 2 rolled a "+diceOne+" and a "+diceTwo);
        System.out.println ("player 2 now has a score of : 
"+playerTwoScore);
        sum=0;
      }
      //to break the loop immediatly if one player wins
      if (playerOneScore>win)
      {
        break;
      }
      break;
    }
  }while (playerOneScore<=win && playerTwoScore<=win );
  if (playerOneScore>win)
  {
    System.out.println ("player 1 wins with a score of : "+playerOneScore);
  }
  else if (playerTwoScore>win)
  {
    System.out.println ("player 2 wins with a score of : "+playerTwoScore);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @scarywombat , thanks for the response. what would be the parameters for the embedded while loop?

Comment: nevermind I used a boolean variable "t", and just set it as positive.thank you for helping me!

Comment: use functions..!

Comment: @TheUltimateAssasin11 : You can add an answer rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an example of why usually one doesn't write all the code in a single place.

Your game is a bit complex, and that approach, putting everything inside `main`, might not work very well (although since I started writing this answer I see you have found a solution). Your code is *somewhat* difficult to follow, and I'm no expert, but I can see at least one issue with it.

In your specific issue, for instance, there could be a **function** in the style of `rollDice(int playerNumber)` which you can call anytime, like when a player must re-roll. As you might have noticed yourself, you basically rewrote the code for each player: it's nice you have just two players, imagine you had ten!

There are endless ways in which you can abstract this problem. It seems to me, if you are starting (or restarting, as you mention), you should check some concepts, like what is a function, and down the road, [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), since Java is all about object-oriented programming.

Comment: thank you for your response, JD Gamboa, initially, I was planning on using separate methods to run in my program (rollDice(), etc), but my prof said he was specifically looking for the full program to be in main.